# How to autofit DataGridView header

Tags: c#, winforms

When i load data in a datagid the columns are chopped off. I'd like to resize the column width so I can see the whole column name on all columns. I have tried every solution of stackoverflow without success. I am guessing winforms has been updated since then.

Comment: You can set it at any time: `[DataGridView].SuspendLayout(); [DataGridView].AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells); 
[DataGridView].ResumeLayout(false);`. You can also add an option (Button? ContextMenuStrip?) that a User can activate to resize the Columns to fit the Cells' content. You should set the `MinimumSize` of ComboBoxColumns: if no data is yet shown, the Column is resized to the Header width (but of course you can call `AutoResizeColumns()` when needed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the AutoSizeColumnsMode property.

For information as to how exactly the properties size the columns, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This works, however the columns are no longer resizable by user

Comment: @Luke101: Yup, you get your choice: autosizing, or user sizing.  Whey you autosize the columns, you will want to pick one column that is set to Fill (or something like that).  It will expand in order to make the control fill the space it's been sized to.  It will also get squeezed if you resize the form (and the control is set to resize as a consequence)

Comment: You could also switch between auto resize and user resize programatically. What I tend to do is set auto resize when I load the datagrid, and then afterwards I set it to user resize. This gives me the desired took and feel for when the grid is loaded, but gives the power back to the user to resize afterwards.